# ошибка pickle: "EOFerror: ran out of input" при загрузке списка из файла

Tags: python

пытаюсь выгрузить из файла список в bytes-файле

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if f.read() == '':
            debtList = []
        else:
            debtList = pcl.load(f)
```

уложенный здесь

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pcl.dump(debtList, f)
```

я получаю ошибку `EOFError: Ran out of input` при запуске, почему так происходит и что с этим делать?

Comment: О чем говорит выдаваемая ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if f.read() == '':
            debtList = []
```

В этот момент файл `f` весь прочитан от начала и до конца, указатель установлен на конец файла. И я не очень понимаю, что и с чем вы тут сравниваете, работает ли нормально сравнение считанных **байтов** со **строкой**.

```py
        else:
            debtList = pcl.load(f)
```

А здесь вы пытаетесь ещё раз прочитать уже прочитанный файл `f` с указателем, установленным на конец файла. Естественно, ничего вы уже не можете прочитать.

Решением может быть, например, установка указателя обратно на начало файла перед повторным его чтением:

```py
        else:
            f.seek(0)
            debtList = pcl.load(f)
```